# How to use bignumber.js with Clojurescript's :npm-deps feature

Tags: clojurescript

I've been following tutorial at https://anmonteiro.com/2017/03/requiring-node-js-modules-from-clojurescript-namespaces/ to use Clojurescript's :npm-deps feature.

Using left-pad works well, but when I tried to use [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) I've hit problems.

This is from my project.clj

```
{:main "npm-deps-test.core"
 :output-to "dev-compiled/npm-deps-test.js",
 :output-dir "dev-compiled",
 :target :nodejs,
 :optimizations :none,
 :source-map true
 :npm-deps {:bignumber.js "4.0.2"
            :left-pad "1.1.3"}}
```

This is code with output:

```
(ns npm-deps-test.core
  (:require [left-pad]
            [bignumber.js :as bignumber]))

(enable-console-print!)

(comment
  (type bignumber)
  ; => #object[Object "function Object() { [native code] }"]

  (aget bignumber "__proto__" "constructor")
  ; => #object[Object "function Object() { [native code] }"]

  (bignumber "123")
  ; #object[TypeError TypeError: module$Users$matus$www$clojure_hacking$npm_deps_test$node_modules$bignumber_js$bignumber is not a function]
  ; => nil

  (new bignumber "124")
  ; #object[TypeError TypeError: module$Users$matus$www$clojure_hacking$npm_deps_test$node_modules$bignumber_js$bignumber is not a constructor]
  ; => nil

  (bignumber. "123")
  ; #object[TypeError TypeError: module$Users$matus$www$clojure_hacking$npm_deps_test$node_modules$bignumber_js$bignumber is not a constructor]
  ; => nil

  (left-pad 42 5 0)
  ; => 00042
  )
```

Any idea why this doesn't work as expected?

Using `[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.671"]`
      `[lein-figwheel "0.5.11"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in the ClojureScript REPL when using `[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.562"]`

```
user=> (require '[bignumber.js :as BigNumber])
nil
user=> (BigNumber. "123")
#object[BigNumber 123]
user=> (-> (BigNumber. "12345678") (.toExponential))
"1.2345678e+7"
```

I would guess that the behaviour you're seeing could be a bug or breaking change in `[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.671"]`.

#### Update:

This does indeed appear to be a bug that was patched today:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/00df4ae8a49005dbbb3ad87bf1a24e71897d74f7

I would suggest that you downgrade to an older (but recent!) version of ClojureScript e.g. `[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.562"]` until there is a new release which includes this patch.